# MS Word \# field code formatting, point to comma

Tags: ms-word, formatting

I would like to format field in MS Word from 500.50 -> 500,50. So, point to comma. It this somehow possible to achieve using Word field formatting? I'm on system where comma is used as digital separator.

I tried this, but I got syntax error.
{=500.00 # "#,##"}

Comment: The "field code language" does not let you specify different decimal point and thousands separator characters from the ones defined in Windows/MacOS, and it uses the same character to detect and format those things. StackOverFlow has probably removed your backslash character, but if that is there, I think you would only get a syntax error if comma "," is your decimal point character, so I'm a bit confused about which way around things are on your system. If comma "," is actually the 1000s separator comma, it doesn't matter where you put it in the format string, it will format 000s anyway.

Answer (score -1):

For numbers less than 1000, you could use a field coded as:

{QUOTE{SET Val "500,50"}"{=INT(Val) \# 0}.{=(Val-INT(Val))*100 \# 00}"}